# Using PropTypes when immutable-js in react-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I am using immutable-js and react-immutable-proptypes in React.

```
// CommentBox.jsx
getInitialState() {
    return {
        comments: Immutable.List.of(
            {author: 'Pete Hunt', text: 'Hey there!'},
            {author: 'Justin Gordon', text: 'Aloha from @railsonmaui'}
        )
    };
},
render(){
    console.log(this.state.comments.constructor);
    return (
      <div className='commentBox container'>
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentForm url={this.props.url} />
        <CommentList comments={this.state.comments} />
      </div>
    );
}


// CommentList.jsx
propTypes: {
    comments: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List),
},

// CommentStore.js
handleAddComment(comment) {
    this.comments.push(comment);
}
```

When the page initialization, it's no problem,all is ok,no warning.
The console log shows the `comments` is `function List(value)`.
When I add a new comment, it looks work well,but there is a warning

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `comments` supplied to
>   `CommentList`, expected instance of `List`. Check the render method of
>   `CommentBox`.

and the console log shows that the `comments` is `function Array()`.
So, why does the `comments` constructor change from `List` to `Array`?

And and I have read http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html#immutable-js-and-flux.

> The messages store could keep track of the users and messages using
>   two lists:
>
> ```
> this.users = Immutable.List();
> this.messages = Immutable.List();
> ```
>
> It should be pretty straightforward to implement functions to process
>   each payload type. For instance, when the store sees a payload
>   representing a new message, we can just create a new record and append
>   it to the messages list:
>
> ```
> this.messages = this.messages.push(new Message({
>   timestamp: payload.timestamp,
>   sender: payload.sender,
>   text: payload.text
> });
> ```
>
> Note that since the data structures are immutable, we need to assign
>   the result of the push function to this.messages.

Comment: `this.comments.push(comment)` expression returns a new list but does not modify the list in place (by definition, since it's immutable)

Comment: I learned this way from http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html#immutable-js-and-flux.

Comment: In that very article they assign the result of the call to the property itself.

Comment: "Note that since the data structures are immutable, we need to assign the result of the push function to this.messages." Please go through that article one more time.

Comment: Thank you.I think I misunderstood the immutable.

Comment: I found the problem.Using `push` for immutable record is no problem, it always return a new immutable record.Before the constructor of CommentStore.`constructor(){this.comments = []}`.

Comment: It always indeed returns a new immutable, but you don't assign it to anywhere.

Comment: No.So the `comments constructor` was `function Array()`.I have changed the CommentStore to `constructor(){ this.comments = Immutable.List(); }`.There is no warning now.

Comment: @Brad did you really add the solution to the question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I came here looking to find a solution that would allow either an array or any sort of iterable object from ImmutableJS to be passed as the prop. In case anyone else finds this useful, here's what I came up with:

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
  PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.Iterable)
]).isRequired
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom validator.

```js
propName: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!List.isList(props[propName]) && !Array.isArray(props[propName])) {
    return new Error(
      'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
      ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```